# iOS Distribution Certificate Acceptance not working

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution, provisioning

I followed the instructions on the iOS developer site, used keychain access to generate a certificate request, and uploaded it to the distribution part of the certificates tab in the provisioning portal.

The instructions say that I should now accept that certificate. Except all it says is the name of the certificate and "issued". There's no place for me to accept it. There isn't even a place for me to delete it. I've searched all over for help, and can't find any.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the person who created the Apple developer account, you need not accept it. It will get automatically accepted after a while. You need to go to the distribution section and it should be there to be downloaded in Certificates->Distribution. You would also need a distribution provisioning profile which is created in a more or less similar fashion.

If you are not the person who created the Apple developer account, then you cannot create a distribution build. Contact the person who has the "Agent" account.

Comment: I am the person who created the account. How long is "a while"? It's in certificates->distribution where it only says "issued"; there is no place to download or delete it. Also, I can't create the distribution provisioning profile without the distribution certificate (it keeps prompting me to make one).

Comment: Just refresh the page and a download/edit/revoke link should appear under the "actions" column. What exactly do you see in the actions column?

Comment: Have been refreshing for the last hour or so. There's nothing in the actions column.

Comment: Yeah. On mine, I see the "issued" part, but nothing under "actions".

Comment: Try logging out and loggin in. I'm sorry, haven't had that issue in my one and a half year experience and many apps. Also, are you enrolled in multiple developer accounts?..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4474/discussion-between-debuggerman-and-mason)